# Xcode 10.3 Simulator Stuck at Apple Logo

Tags: xcode, xcode10.3

I have two Xcodes in my mac :

- Xcode 10.1 : I can run all the apps in simulators and doesn't give any problems
- Xcode 10.3 : I can run the apps on real devices but while running on simulators they stuck on apple logo

I have tried restarting the Xcode & mac, but still it didn't help me.

While the simulator is stuck at apple logo, Xcode displays launching "app name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UnInstalling Xcode 10.3 and Re-Installing of Xcode resolved the issue.